# Fromat datagridview cells based on SQL logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have the following SQL statement that checks for duplicate date ranges within my data set.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i
  JOIN [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i2 
  on i.cli = i2.cli
  and i.quantity = i2.quantity
  and i.unitcost = i2.unitcost
  and i.totalcost = i2.totalcost
  and i.[description] = i2.[description]

  and ((i.FromDate <= i2.ToDate)  and  (i.ToDate >= i2.FromDate))

  WHERE i.id<>i2.id

  AND (i2.[bill]=0 AND i2.[Billed Month] is Null AND i2.currentbill = 0)
```

I would like to use this SQL logic, to check each line of my data grid view and then format each line accordingly if the condition is met. i.e. the data ranges overlap.

Something like this, I am just not sure how to incorporate the SQL element?

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView2.Rows

        If "SQL condition for the specific line is true" Then 
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you mean you should take some value from each row,check if its duplicate and change color of that line based on the check?if this is the case you can use some function for checking,right?

Comment: Yes, I wan to highlight the row if it is a duplicate range. i.e. if the line item appears in the SQL select statement.

Comment: ok now whats is the problem,you can use a checking function to check if the item is present in database.and you have the code to change the color.

Comment: I am relatively new to vb. I am struggling to figure out how to code this, hence my question. Are you able to provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
 For intcount=0 to DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView2.Rows.count-1

        If checkdata(intcount)=true Then 
            datagridview2.rows(intcount).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
```

and add a checking function in your code like:

```
 Private Function checkdata(ByVal row As Integer) As Boolean
            Dim da As SqlDataReader
            Dim command As SqlCommand
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.Connection = connection
            command.CommandText = "Your query for checking if the item in specified row is in database"
            da = command.ExecuteReader
            If da.HasRows Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Function
```

specify the checking in the command text in fucntion.Just Provided this as an example,you may modify it upon our own needs.

Comment: The First section of this code has a couple of errors: 'System.Data.SqlClient.Row' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'. and 'checkdata' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. The Second section errors on: Variable 'command' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: i just provided an example.you can modify it based on your needs.here i am using componentone controls so dont know how to deal with vb basic controls.i just wanted to provide a logic for your need.